# ¿Como cambiar todas las columnas de una tabla en Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Buenas tengo una pregunta, se como editar un usuario, pero tengo una columna de trabajos que el usuario debe marcar cada dia y para que una vez el usuario la marque y no vuelva a aparecer debe cambiar su propiedad read_at de 0 a 1, bueno esa parte está perfecta la tengo hecha, pero ahora como puedo modificar en un comando o en un controller, que toda la columna read_at de mi tabla que tenga el read_at en el valor 1, cambie a 0. A lo mucho tengo el modelo en este caso

> Trabajos::

pero que tendría que poner para hacer lo que quiero, si me dejo entender. En este caso el modelo Trabajos le sirve a la tabla trabajos que tiene los campos. Id, Nombre,periodo, read_at. Donde id se autoincrementa y sirve como llave primaria, Nombre que sirve para el nombre del trabajo, periodo para saber si el trabajo es diario, mensual, anual, semestral y read_at para contener los valores 0(Aun no se realizó el trabajo) y 1(El trabajo se realizó) para saber si se realizó o no el trabajo durante ese día y como veran el objetivo es que al siguiente dia pueda poner todos los campos que tengan el periodo en diario y el read_at en 1 vuelvan a tener el read_at en 0. Espero puedan ayudarme. Como podria hacer la edición con eloquent. Espero se me entienda les agradezco mucho de antemano.

Comment: Con update podrías... Que has intentado?

Comment: @porloscerros Ψ  A lo mucho creo que con esto podria usarlo, pero no se como usar el update o cual es su sintaxis `Trabajos::where('read_at','=', 1)->update();`

Comment: El método update espera como parámetro un array con la clave/valor correspondiente a la columna/valor que quieres actualizar. Está en la documentación de Larave l[Mass Updates](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#updates).